# How to convert compressed tiff image(Group4 - CCITT_T.6) to PNG, using ImageMagick's convert.exe?

Tags: imagemagick, tiff, imagemagick-convert

I want to convert compressed tiff(Group4 - CCITT_T.6) to PNG format image.

I am using ImageMagick's[6.9.1-10 Q8 x86 2015-07-25 http://www.imagemagick.org] convert.exe for this task.

Link to compressed tiff:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lsNRRRnjlrzf_Gdc1fArkayn3FgR7L1T/view?usp=sharing

Link to uncompressed tiff:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CzhafYeRTh2Z8p8CbFiytTi4FsZl2koe/view?usp=sharing

This command works, because tif image is uncompressed:

`convert.exe uncompressed.tif -auto-orient -strip test.png`

Below command does NOT work becuase tif image is compressed(Group4 CCITT_T.6):

`convert.exe CCITT_T.6_Compressed.TIF -auto-orient -strip test.png`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried anything? If so, then please show that.

You can using ImageMagick to convert TIFF to PNG simply by

```
convert.exe image.tif image.png
```

or if that fails, then

```
convert.exe image.tif -type bilevel image.png
```

If those do not work, the post the error message. Also post a link to your image. You may have to upload it to some free hosting service that won't change the format and put the link here.

Note that there is a Windows convert.exe also. Be sure to use the ImageMagick one or rename it so that there is no confusion.

Comment: I tried `convert.exe CCITT_T.6_Compressed.TIF -type bilevel test.png` 
Below error is thrown: 
`"convert.exe: CCITT_T.6_Compressed.TIF: Bad value 0 for "ResolutionUnit" tag. '_TIFFVSetField' @ error/tiff.c/TIFFErrors/645".`

Comment: `ImageMagick-7.0.7-11-portable-Q16-x64\convert.exe -verbose CCITT_T.6_Compressed_2KB.TIF -type bilevel test.png`  
`CCITT_T.6_Compressed_2KB.TIF TIFF 985x932 985x932+0+0 1-bit Bilevel Gray 2358B 0.000u 0:00.002`  
`CCITT_T.6_Compressed_2KB.TIF=>test.png TIFF 985x932 985x932+0+0 1-bit Bilevel Gray 6373B 0.047u 0:00.045`  
`convert.exe: CCITT_T.6_Compressed_2KB.TIF: Bad value 0 for "ResolutionUnit" tag. '_TIFFVSetField' @ error/tiff.c/TIFFErrors/645.`

Comment: Was that message a Warning or an Error? If the former, then it will not matter and you should get an output. If an error, then your file is corrupt or malformed. Are you able to post that TIFF keeping it unchanged or post a link to it from some other hosting service that won't change the format? If so, then I can check it out on my system. Also what is your ImageMagick version from `convert -version`?

Comment: Yes, you are right.. looks like above message is warning, but it is able to generate test.png  This solves my issue I suppose... I appreciate your kinds help.. many many thanks...

Comment: With TIFF files you can suppress Warnings with ImageMagick commands by adding -quiet to your command line before reading the input image. `convert -quiet image.tif ... result.png`

Comment: Looks like its NOT a warning its error `CCITT_T.6_Compressed_2KB.TIF: Bad value 0 for "ResolutionUnit" tag. '_TIFFVSetField' @ error/tiff.c/TIFFErrors/645.`
Though on windows OS from command console even with this error its able to generate the test.png...
But from alfresco java api its throwing contentIOException...

Comment: Caused by: org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.ContentIOException: 02190020 Failed to perform ImageMagick transformation: 
Execution result: 
   os:      Windows 7
   command:    ImageMagick-7.0.7-11-portable-Q16-x64\convert.exe ImageMagickContentTransformerWorker_source_5314598831539770735.tiff[0] `-auto-orient -strip -quiet` ImageMagickContentTransformerWorker_target_887477043587691475.png
   succeeded:  false
   exit code:  1
   out:        
org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.magick.ImageMagickContentTransformerWorker.transformInternal(ImageMagickContentTransformerWorker.java:205)

Comment: C:\convert.exe -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.1-10 Q8 x86 2015-07-25 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2015 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo freetype jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr openexr pangocairo png ps rsvg tiff webp xml zlib

Comment: Link to compressed tif image, download it to recreate the exception:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lsNRRRnjlrzf_Gdc1fArkayn3FgR7L1T/view?usp=sharing

Comment: For me, using ImageMagick 6.9.10.34 or 7.0.8.34, your file will not convert to PNG. I am getting errors and not warnings. Note that for ImageMagick 7, you should be using magick.exe and not convert.exe. I do not know enough about TIFF files to say what is wrong other than it is malformed and ImageMagick objects. If you want someone to look further into it, post your TIFF file and concern at https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewforum.php?f=3

Comment: If I use IM 6.9.3.0, then I can convert the file. But not with the current version. So there has been a change in ImageMagick that is more strict on warnings or on this issue.

Comment: I have sent the image to the Imagemagick developers with my comments about it working in old versions but not new ones.